# HttpClient wrong encoding in Content-Disposition

Tags: c#, http, content-disposition

I am POST-ing an image with `HttpClient` and it works well for files with Latin names, but as soon as a name contains any non-ASCII characters it gets transformed to a sequence of question marks. If I create an html form and use a browser to post the file, the file name is sent in UTF8 and the target server perfectly accepts it.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var streamContent = new StreamContent(someImageFileStream);
    streamContent.Headers.Add(
        "Content-Disposition",
        "form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"Тест.jpg\"");

    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(streamContent);

    await client.PostAsync("http://localhost.fiddler/", content);
}
```

This produces the following request:

```
POST http://localhost/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="e6fe89be-e652-4fe3-8859-8c7a339c5550"
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 10556

--e6fe89be-e652-4fe3-8859-8c7a339c5550
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="????.jpg"

...here goes the contents of the file...
```

I understand that `HttpClient` might work according to some standard, but anyway, is there any workaround?

**UPDATE**:  The external API doesn't want to accept the format `filename*=utf-8''Тест.jpg`, it expects `filename="Тест.jpg"`.

Comment: `filename*=` (or rather `<fieldname>*=`) is a correct yet little supported method of encoding values that aren't US-ASCII. Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/93551/3012385).

Comment: Did you ever solve it?

Comment: @ShiranDror See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found a way to force `MultipartFormDataContent` to forget the ancient RFCs and use UTF8 instead. The trick is to use reflection to overwrite the `DefaultHttpEncoding` defined in the internal static class `HttpRuleParser`.

```
typeof(HttpClient)
  .Assembly
  .GetType("System.Net.Http.HttpRuleParser")
  .GetField("DefaultHttpEncoding", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
  .SetValue(null, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Not sure which bad consequences that might cause, but I suppose there are none.

Comment: Faced the same issue when using RestClient and HttpClient, isn't there any other way than tampering with internal fields?

Answer (score 8):

This is another way to workaround the limitation of HttpClient without tampering with internal fields. Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955802/1932338).

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var streamContent = new StreamContent(someImageFileStream);
    streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition",
        new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"Тест.jpg\"").
        Select(b => (char)b).ToArray()));

    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(streamContent);
    await client.PostAsync("http://localhost.fiddler/", content);
}
```

I confirm that even .net core 2.2 doesn't have proper support for uploading files whose names contain non-ASCII characters. HttpClient does work according to some standard but Java servers don't care about that standard and expect UTF-8 formatted headers.

Comment: "even .net core 2.2 doesn't have proper support" MultipartFormDataContent\StreamContent seems to works 100% by the spec (RFC's) afaics. The problem is that no one else seems to, not even Microsofts old stuff like HttpRequest\HttpPostedFile. I think Microsoft should have given IETF the finger on this one and just encoded filename as plain utf8.

Comment: I've banged my head for a whole day on this problem (with .Net 6). My understanding of the problem is somewhat limited, but HttpClient's default behaviour of transforming the file's name to RFC 1342 (=?utf-8?B?...) isn't handled by the external API my app is calling. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a header that you built yourself, use the .NET library:

```
streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { 
        Name = "image", 
        FileName = "Тест.jpg" };
```

That creates the header per the [web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) and [RFC5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987#page-3).

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=image; filename="=?utf-8?B?0KLQtdGB0YIuanBn?="
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the API where I POST to doesn't accept this format.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, you can also remove the "*filename**"

```
//It deletes filename* parametr
foreach (var content in multipartContent) {
   var headerContent = content.Headers.ContentDisposition.Parameters.Where(x => x.Name == "filename*").SingleOrDefault();
   if(headerContent != null)
      content.Headers.ContentDisposition.Parameters.Remove(headerContent);
}
```