# Issue with sending files with non-ASCII filenames in multipart form data using C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, multipartform-data

I'm encountering a peculiar issue when attempting to upload files with non-ASCII filenames (e.g., filenames containing Russian characters) to a server using C#'s HttpClient and multipart form data. Strangely, while the server fails to recognize the filename and doesn't seem to receive the file itself when using non-ASCII filenames, it works perfectly fine when I send the same file with an English-letter filename. Also it works when I send the same file with a Russian filename using **Postman** and **Javascript**.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

string filePath = "C:/path/to/file/файл.pdf"; // Example non-ASCII filename
var stream = new StreamContent(System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath));
stream.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
content.Add(stream, "file", "файл.pdf");

var response = await client.PostAsync("https://example.com/upload", content);
```

I've tried encoding the filename using `Uri.EscapeDataString()` and `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`, but to no avail. The issue persists.

Could this problem be related to how I'm encoding the filename? Or are there other factors I should consider?

Comment: What’s the specific error you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error, server just not see the file

Comment: I would use a tool like fiddler or wireshark to check the request. If it looks ok, then it’s the service

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004296/httpclient-wrong-encoding-in-content-disposition

Comment: did you check your stream that it contains the data?

Comment: Dublicated question's answers is no longer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upload file using HttpWebRequest  instead HttpClient

example code:

```
 public static void HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType, NameValueCollection nvc)
    {

        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
        {
            requestStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
            byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
            requestStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
        }
        requestStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, "aaa.pdf", contentType);
        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
        requestStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();

        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        requestStream.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        WebResponse wresp = null;
        try
        {
            wresp = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
            string result = reader2.ReadToEnd();
        }

        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (var stream = ex?.Response?.GetResponseStream())
                if (stream != null)
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (wresp != null)
            {
                wresp.Close();
                wresp = null;
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            request = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` is deprecated. You are also mssing a bunch of `using`s and you appear to have forgotten that `stream.CopyTo` exists.

Comment: @Charlieface for now it is the only working code, if you have better alternative pls out your answer and I will accept it. I already tested dublicated question's answers and they are no longer works

Comment: You can always use a custom `ByteArrayContent` with `HttpClient` there is no need to use `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: @Charlieface can you provide example?

Answer (score 1):

About 2 years ago i have same problem.I solved this issue used **httpwebrequest** instead of httpclient.This problem occurred on httpclient because it overrides request headers filename on non english characters.